# GPS locations are not received during a 999 call

Tags: android, gps

I have an Android app (2.1 to 2.3) that successfully receives locations from the GPS provider when a call is initiated. This is tested and works. However, when I dial 999 (using an authorised emergency test) no locations are received from the GPS provider.

I note in the UK Android displays an emergency screen to show you are making a 999 call. This seems to be different to the emergency mode I've seen discussed for the US which also locks the phone. In the UK it stays unlocked.

Does anyone know if Android purposely stops GPS locations in the UK from being received during a 999 call? It's strange because the network provider (inc. Wi-Fi) locations still come through, though the logs do show it is from a cached location.

Thanks.

Comment: Could be possible that is giving the emergency provider full access to the GPS service, just as a precaution. Is this just a curiosity thing, or does your app need to be receiving location data while the user is having and emergency?

Comment: Yes I'm working to requirements that state the app has to receive GPS data by 20 seconds into a call. I'm wondering if it is turning GPS off during the 999 call for power saving reasons, yet the API triggers no state changes in the LocationListener.

Comment: Out of interest, how are they sent to the 999 operator? Is there an established protocol for this? Do other smartphones do this too (eg iPhones?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming that normal GPS operation is interrupted for emergency services.

There are two modes of operation that most phones have with respect to GPS: standalone, and assisted.  User level apps use the output of standalone, and assisted call flows are used for emergency calls.

The GPS chip is executing a predetermined routine in communication with a server which usually involves integrating measurements over a long period of time in order to maximize signal strength.  This interrupts normal operation.

Comment: Thanks, is this US specific? Currently in the UK the location is gathered from the mobile cell networks and not the phones. If the phone still tries to do this in the UK, even without a server, I guess it has the same impact. So does the emergency call have to close down before I can get a GPS result sent to the app, or will it eventually come through whilst the emergency call is active?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/999_(emergency_telephone_number)#Location

"for more specific traces senior authority must be acquired and an expensive operation can be conducted to trace the mobile phone to within a few metres."

I'm guess this means that GPS measurements are taken, but are only made available in some circumstances.  I can't imagine any emergency callflow taking more than 1 full minute, after which the GPS chip should be available.  However, I cannot speak to what the OS of the phone may or may not allow.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I appreciate your time. We've decided to run using a non 999 number, as at this stage it's just a trial app and will give us the data we need.